# What are the fake police checkpoints in Mexico looking for?

Tags: safety, legal, driving, road-trips, mexico

I'm not entirely sure if this is the right place to ask this, but my reason for asking is travel; and travel safety (as well as sheer curiosity).

Last week I came across a clearly<sup>1</sup> fake<sup>2</sup> police checkpoint in Mexico, and they had me (and my two passengers) get out of the car, did a superficial search of the car, then sent us on our way.

This makes me wonder:

*What are these unofficial checkpoints looking for?*  And the followup question *How can I reduce the chances of being stopped/detained/interrogated/robbed/kidnapped/murdered/raped/whatever at one?*

I've heard many unsubstantiated rumors:

- They're "only" looking for rival criminals (probably drug cartels)
- They're looking for valuables to steal
- They're looking for wealthy people to kidnap

I also realize there may not be a single correct answer to this question, as each checkpoint may be looking for something different; but hopefully a generally useful answer can be provided.

---

<sup>1</sup>I was an hour from the nearest town, but the uniforms all said *Policía Municipal*, and their vehicles were faded (police vehicles are *usually* very nice in Mexico), and from the state of Guanajuato, although we were in San Luis Potosí.  This would be like driving through Texas and coming across a police checkpoint manned by the LAPD.  Pretty fishy.

<sup>2</sup>This question is about criminals (I believe usually drug cartels) impersonating police officers.

Comment: Please don't call them "Fake Police" - "Freelance Police" is the preferred term!

Comment: most likely they're looking on anything of value, be it hostages, stuff, or money.

Comment: There must be pretty bad law enforcement in Mexico if these guys can operate openly for more than an hour.

Comment: @joshua: They generally work in (voluntary and/or coerced) cooperation  with law enforcement.

Answer (score 11):

The category on [Driving in Mexico on Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Mexico#Driving) has a couple of things to say:

> Never drive above the speed limit or run stop signs/red lights as
>   Mexican police will use any excuse to pull over tourists and give you
>   a ticket. If pulled over by a police officer soliciting a bribe, do
>   not pay the amount requested, but pull out USD$50 or 500 pesos, and
>   explain that it is all you have. This technique has worked in the past
>   (but it does not work in Mexico City), but it is corruption.
>   Corruption also is a crime in Mexico, so make a conscious choice. The
>   fine for speeding could be as much as US$100, depending on the city.
>
> As of April 2011, Police across the country are cracking down on
>   drunken driving, particularly in Mexico City, the larger cities and
>   the beach resorts. There are random checkpoints throughout the country
>   in which every driver has to stop and take an automated inebriation
>   test. If you fail, you will end up in a Mexican prison. If you
>   wouldn't drive drunk back home, don't do it in Mexico.

So in this case, it would imply they're looking for three things:

- drunk drivers
- speeding drivers
- drugs
- the opportunity to elicit a bribe (also can be coupled with the previous three items)

That is for REAL Mexican police stops.

---

Now as for fake police stops, the US Consulate has this to say, as of 2010:

> U.S. officials have clarified an earlier travel advisory that warned
>   Americans against traveling after dark to Puerto Penasco, Mexico, also
>   known as Rocky Point.
>
> The U.S. Consulate in Nogales, Mexico, had issued the warning because
>   travelers have been stopped by phony Mexican police roadblocks.
>
> In an e-mail obtained by the Arizona Daily Star, the consulate stands
>   behind its advisory, but clarifies that the warning only advises
>   against traveling on the highway to Puerto Penasco at night and didn't
>   apply to other highways in the Mexican state of Sonora or in the city
>   of Rocky Point itself.

A few other results seem to indicate some prejudice against people from the state of Arizona specifically, as seen on [this thread](http://www.abovetopsecret.com/forum/thread575075/pg1):

> ...there's people down in Mexico looking for people from Arizona. Fake
>   police and fake roadblocks. I doubt anything good will happen to
>   someone who is found out to be from Arizona.
>
> There was a tourism ad released not too long ago that Sheriff Arpaio
>   sees as threatening to AZ citizens, and this may be related to that.

Comment: This is about the _official_ police... I'm asking about the unofficial ones (i.e. criminals posing as police) (Question updated to make this more clear)

Comment: so by unofficial you mean fake? :)

Comment: updated answer to include fake police stops

Comment: Yes, fake... that's probably a better word; question further updated accordingly. :)